# What is the best way to format string representation of number in iOS

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

In the iOS app I am writing, I receive a json object with a string representation of a price, something like this:

```
{
  "price":"20000"
}
```

And I'd like to format it with commas for ease of readability, and I have found a way, but I feel like it is a crazy clunky (I probably just didn't use the right terms in google).

```
 NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
 [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 NSString price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[price intValue]]]];
```

It seems overly complex to me that to get the proper formatting I have to

1. Convert the NSString to an int.
2. Convert the int to a NSNumber.
3. Convert the NSNumber to an NSString.
4. <strike>Create a new string with the proper format</strike> (@david/@wain showed me how to drop this step!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best for currency would be the `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *price = @([priceTextFromJSON doubleValue]);
NSString *priceText = [formatter stringFromNumber:price];
```

Comment: Since the original price is a string, this generates a `Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSNumber *'`.  It does eliminate the last step though, where I add the $, at least.

Comment: If you have any control over that JSON you should send numbers as numbers. Also note that if you intent on doing *any* calculations with money then you should *always* do them as `NSDecimalNumber`s

Comment: Be sure that the price is always returned in the users locale setting or this will show the wrong currency symbol.

Comment: Unfortunately, the json is provided as-is.  Luckily there are no calculations, I just need so display thevalues.  You suggest using the NSDecimalNumber in this instance because a price, and not for any other reason, correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine.

You could use `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:price]` to deal with the source price a little better if it isn't an integer.

You could use `[formatter setCurrencySymbol:@"$"]` to deal with the symbol instead of `stringWithFormat`.

These changes would make the implementation you have more robust and elegant.